# hOW can i add external jars in my build.xml

Tags: ant, build

hOW can i add external jars in my build.xml.
i am getting compilation error while running my build.xml.some jars are missing.how can i add them in my build.xml.

my build.xml looks like this

```
<project name="HUDSONSTATUSWS" default="dist" basedir=".">
    <description>
        Web Services build file
    </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="src"/>
  <property name="build" location="build"/>
  <property name="dist"  location="dist"/>
  <property name="webcontent"  location="WebContent"/>

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init"
    description="compile the source " >
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="dist" depends="compile"
    description="generate the distribution" >

    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib"/>

    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/lib/MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar" basedir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="war" depends="compile"
    description="generate the distribution war" >

    <!-- Create the war distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/war"/>

    <!-- Follow standard WAR structure -->
    <copydir dest="${dist}/war/build/WEB-INF/" src="${webcontent}/WEB-INF/" />
    <copydir dest="${dist}/war/build/WEB-INF/classes/" src="${build}" />

    <jar jarfile="${dist}/war/HelloWorld-${DSTAMP}.war" basedir="${dist}/war/build/"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
    description="clean up" >

    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to specify the classpath for `javac`, using the `classpath` or `classpathref` attribute, or a nested `classpath` element.

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html for details. The ant documentation is very well written, exhaustive, and full of examples. It's there to be read.